# Performance of reservoir sampling vs. getting the length of a list and picking random elements

Tags: performance, haskell, haskell-criterion

I have written two functions to pick a random element out of a list of unknown length. The first uses reservoir sampling (with a reservoir of size 1), and the second gets the length of the list to pick a random index and return it. For some reason, the former is much faster.

The first function uses a single traversal and pick each element with probability (1/i), where i is the index of the element in the list. It results in a equal probability of picking each element.

```
pickRandom :: [a] -> IO a
pickRandom [] = error "List is empty"
pickRandom (x:xs) = do
  stdgen <- newStdGen
  return (pickRandom' xs x 1 stdgen)

-- Pick a random number using reservoir sampling
pickRandom' :: (RandomGen g) => [a] -> a -> Int -> g -> a
pickRandom' [] xi _ _ = xi
pickRandom' (x:xs) xi n gen =
  let (rand, gen') = randomR (0, n) gen in
  if (rand == 0) then
    pickRandom' xs x (n + 1) gen' -- Update value
  else
    pickRandom' xs xi (n + 1) gen' -- Keep previous value
```

The second version traverses the list once to get its length, and then picks an index between 0 and the length of the input list (-1) to get one of the element, again with equal probability. The expected number of traversal of the list 1.5:

```
-- Traverses the list twice
pickRandomWithLen :: [a] -> IO a
pickRandomWithLen [] = error "List is empty"
pickRandomWithLen xs = do
  gen <- newStdGen
  (e, _) <- return $ randomR (0, (length xs) - 1) gen
  return $ xs !! e
```

Here is the code I use for benchmarking these two functions:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  gen <- newStdGen
  let size = 2097152
      inputList = getRandList gen size
  defaultMain [ bench "Using length" (pickRandomWithLen inputList)
              , bench "Using reservoir" (pickRandom inputList)
              ]
```

Here is a stripped output:

```
benchmarking Using reservoir
mean: 82.72108 ns, lb 82.02459 ns, ub 83.61931 ns, ci 0.950

benchmarking Using length
mean: 17.12571 ms, lb 16.97026 ms, ub 17.37352 ms, ci 0.950
```

In other terms, the first function is about 200 times faster than the second. I expected the runtime  to be influenced mainly by random number generation and the number of list traversals (1 vs. 1.5). What other factors can explain such a huge difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your benchmarked actions don't actually evaluate the result,

```
pickRandom :: [a] -> IO a
pickRandom [] = error "List is empty"
pickRandom (x:xs) = do
  stdgen <- newStdGen
  return (pickRandom' xs x 1 stdgen)
```

only gets a new `StdGen` and returns a thunk. That's pretty immediate.

```
pickRandomWithLen :: [a] -> IO a
pickRandomWithLen [] = error "List is empty"
pickRandomWithLen xs = do
  gen <- newStdGen
  (e, _) <- return $ randomR (0, (length xs) - 1) gen
  return $ xs !! e
```

computes the length of the list and then returns a thunk, that is of course much slower.

Forcing both to evaluate the result,

```
return $! ...
```

makes the `length` using version **much** faster,

```
benchmarking Using length
mean: 14.65655 ms, lb 14.14580 ms, ub 15.16942 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 2.631668 ms, lb 2.378186 ms, ub 2.937339 ms, ci 0.950
variance introduced by outliers: 92.581%
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking Using reservoir
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 47.00930 s
mean: 451.5571 ms, lb 448.4355 ms, ub 455.7812 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 18.50427 ms, lb 14.45557 ms, ub 24.74350 ms, ci 0.950
found 4 outliers among 100 samples (4.0%)
  2 (2.0%) high mild
  2 (2.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 38.511%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

(after forcing the input list to be evaluated before by printing its sum), because that needs only one call to the PRNG, while the reservoir sampling uses `length list - 1` calls.

The difference would probably be smaller if a faster PRNG than a `StdGen` is used.

Indeed, using [`System.Random.Mersenne`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mersenne-random/1.0.0.1/doc/html/System-Random-Mersenne.html) instead of `StdGen` (requires that `pickRandom'` has `IO a` result type, and since it offers no generation in a specific range but only default range skews the distribution of picked elements a little, but since we're only interested in the time needed for the pseudo-random number generation, that's not important), the time for the reservoir sampling drops to

```
mean: 51.83185 ms, lb 51.77620 ms, ub 51.91259 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 482.4712 us, lb 368.4433 us, ub 649.1758 us, ci 0.950
```

(the `pickRandomWithLen` time doesn't change measurably, of course, since it uses only one generation). A roughly nine-fold speedup, that shows that the pseudo-random generation is the dominant factor.